# Unable to center a UIImage in a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uiimage

I have the following code in ViewDidLoad of my UiTableViewController:

```
UIImage *noImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pathOfNoImageFile];
UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:noImage];

[imageview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
imageview.frame = workingFrame;
[self.scrollview addSubview:imageview];
workingFrame.origin.x = workingFrame.origin.x + workingFrame.size.width;

[self.scrollview setPagingEnabled:YES];
[self.scrollview setContentSize:
      CGSizeMake(workingFrame.origin.x,workingFrame.size.height)];
```

I therefore am only able to see the image partially and have attached a screen shot.

[image]

What can i do to fix it? I have Googled and looked at several Stack Overflow questions but have not been able to have it work. Please suggest.  I have a scrollview in the uitableviewcell. I need to center my image vertically .

Comment: You want to center your image in the visible portion of the scrollview?    What is the size of your scrollview, that's unclear from what you've posted here.

Comment: 280 x 84 in interface builder.....Your comment was interesting as I adjusted my cell height to 100.0f and now I see the image in center. Does that sound right?

Comment: Yeah, especially if that is your workingFrame size

Comment: cool thanks for the feedback. You are more then welcome to move your answer to an answer I will select it as the correct one. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scrollview/cell size will need to be big enough to hold the imageview that you want to display.  Looks like one or both is too small so I would adjust your sizes accordingly.